# 3-Color Scale to change color in different columns from data in another column

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, excel-2011

I have an Excel document with First Name and Last name in columns A and B. Data related to those names in column C in Percentages.

I have been able to conditionally format percentile in the data column C based on values in a 3-Color Scale but I need the Names in Columns A and B to change color from the data in C using the same 3-Color Scale formula. I cannot seem to find anything online that teaches or shows me how to use 3-Color sliding scale to change color in different cells than data it is reading.

Can someone please show me how to match color or use IF formula to change color of columns A and B (names) from data in C (Percentages) and keep 3-Color sliding color scale?

Answer (score 0):

Based on Excel 2007 (but you've waited a while for any other response) you may notice that if you use Format Painter to copy the colour scale to your First Name and Last Name columns their highlighting did not change. However I think you will find that if you then, temporarily, replace a name with a number highlighting is acquired. The conditional formatting rules have been copied by Format Painter but there is no visible change. The reason I think is because the colour scales are numeric and simply are not applicable to names. If you want to copy the colours you will probably need VBA (though your question is not tagged with that).